# ASP.Net Web API: What to do about property duplication between DTO and Domain objects

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

Let's say I have a `ToDoItemModel` concept like below:

```
public class ToDoItemModel
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

This would be my DTO object. I also need to be able to call a few methods on a `ToDoItem`, for example `TransformTitle()` or an overwritten `ToString()` property:

```
public class ToDoItem
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }


   public void TransformTitle(){
       this.Title = TranformationLogic();
   }

   public override string ToString()
   {
       return this.Title;
   }
}
```

I'm planning to use `ToDoItemModel` as a DTO in the controller (when the info is POSTed from the client. The `ToDoItem` would be used to run some logic on the data before being saved in the DB.

However we've got duplication going on between the Model and the Domain object (in terms of their public properties). That doesn't feel right. What's the best way to resolve this duplication? Should the model be passed into `ToDoItem` somehow?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/jasontaylordev/NorthwindTraders/blob/master/Src/Application/Customers/Queries/GetCustomersList/CustomerLookupDto.cs

Comment: What exactly you mean by property duplication? You have a typical situation for using Automapper, to copy one object to another. You can do some transformations on your DTO object and then just map it with Automapper to the domain object. That's what Automapper is intended to be used for, for easy copying similar objects, or even objects that have exactly the same properties (like in this case).